# Cannot ssh with password to Raspberry

Tags: pi-3, ssh

I have set up a raspberry pi 3 on my local network with a raspbian lite image. After activating ssh though raspi-config, I also enabled password authentication with  `PasswordAuthentication yes` on  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Using `ssh -vv raspbery` I obtain the following result:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.0.18" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.18 [192.168.0.18] port 22. 
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/augustin/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/augustin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/augustin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/augustin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/augustin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/augustin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/augustin/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/augustin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1   Raspbian-10+deb9u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.18:22 as 'augustin'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection reset by 192.168.0.18 port 22
```

when I tail the /etc/log/auth.logs on the raspberry I get the following line:

```
fatal: No supported key exchange algorithms [preauth]
```

The funny thing is I can totally ssh from my raspberry pi to my ubuntu machine. Any hints on what is happening here ?

Comment: Without knowing what you did no one can tell. Post output of `ssh -vv pi@raspberrypi.local`

Comment: I added the logs in the question

Comment: You are trying to log  in with user _augustin_. Is there a user _augustin_ on the raspi? Have you tried to login with `pi@192.168.0.18`?

Comment: The user was added beforehand and also in the sudoer group. Log in as pi results in the same effect

Comment: please post your sshd_config (without commented lines) (`key_load_public: No such file or directory` sounds like a wrong path to your authorized_keys or missing HostKey)